# NSFetchedResultsController on a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am implementing an `NSIncrementalStore` and I need to perform a paginated fetch and maintain the order of the elements within the request, then display the results in a table and maintain an `NSFetchedResultsController` associated with the query.
I will try to explain my self better with an example

I have two entities, Entity1 and Entity2. Entity1 has a one-to-many relationship with Entity2 and since the fetch implies too many objects I want to perform a paginated request. I need to maintain the order of the objects arriving from the server so the objects are stored in an `NSOrderSet`. There is no inverse relation between Entity2 and Entity1.

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to instantiate the `NSFetchRequest` in this case.

I've read about pre-fetched relationships using `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` but the `NSFetchRequest` its instantiated with Entity1 as entity (`[fetchRequest setEntity:[Entity1 class]]`) in all examples I read. I need a set of Entity2 objects.

Another idea was to use a fetched property but since I can't  (and I don't want to) perform a sort on the request, I discarded it.

I hope I was clear and thanks Marcus Zarra in advance for encouraging me to ask this question.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need an inverse relationship.  Core Data really should require them instead of just a warning.  With an inverse this question becomes simple.  Without an inverse it is all but impossible.

Assuming you add the inverse (as you should :) then you set up your `NSFetchRequest` against Entity2 with a predicate of "entity1 == %@" and you will get your results back.  From there you can adjust the `NSFetchRequest` to handle the pagination.